# can't clone repo from bitbucket on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a repo from Bitbucket on Ubuntu and it fails with:

```
fatal: https://user@bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

But if I execute the exact same command on my Mac it works fine.

The command I am using is:

```
git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git
```

What could be the issue on Ubuntu?

Comment: Pls add more information on how you are doing the clone i.e the clone command you use .

Comment: I updated the post with the command

Comment: Can you access other arbitrary external https sites from this computer?  If a proxy or captive portal is redirecting your request, the query would obviously not be reaching a valid Git repo.

Comment: What are the version of git used in both instances?

Comment: On the Mac `git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)`
On Ubuntu `1.9.1`

Comment: So we found that we cannot clone from any bitbucket repo from that machine, but we can clone from github and access other external https sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ***`ssh`*** protocol instead of ***`http/https`***.

Using http/https you will have to type your password every time you have to "talk" to the server.

Using ssh will use the `ssh keys` and you will not have to type in username password every time.

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git
```

---

#### `Permission denied (publickey)`

You get this error since you don't have ssh keys on any of your platforms.
Set the keys, add them to your account and you are all set to go.

---

#### `Create ssh keys`

```
# create the key pair.
ssh-keygen -t rsa

# echo the key (pub) to the screen and copy it to clipboard
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

---

#### `Add the keys to your bitbucket account`

- Login to your Bitbucket account
  Choose avatar > Settings from the application menu.
- Choose SSH keys and paste the key you have copied from the first step

[image]

---

## ***Note:***

Repeat this step on each machine you need to connect to your account or copy the same keys to all your machines. Both ways will work.

Comment: We got it work with ssh. But I would like to know why it did not work with https.

Comment: why `http/http` did not work? there can be several reasons: cached password, firewall, your server does not support http/https and more. what i'm trying to day that there can be several reasons and it can take a while to figure it out in the ping pong comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the command would be either https

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git
```

or ssh

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git
```

Comment: The https clone fails with or without the user name on the command line on Ubuntu and works in both cases on the Mac. And the ssh clone fails on both platforms with `Permission denied (publickey).